# Allowing a generic to only be an array key of an object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a factory function that accepts a key from an object to filter on. Here's the relevant TS:

```js
function getNodesOfTypeFactory<
  K extends keyof T,
  T extends { [key: K]: any[] },
>(aryKey: K): (node: T) => T[K] {
```

In short I want to tell it that I have an object of type `T` that has a key of type `K` that is an array.  It's complaining at me that `key` needs to be of type `string | number`.  Any thoughts?

another failed attempt:

```js
function foo<
    T,
    K extends keyof T,
    >(key: K, node: T extends { [key]: any[] }) {
// -------------------------------------------^ '?' expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using a key type like `K` you need to use the mapped types syntax:

```js
function getNodesOfTypeFactory<
  K extends keyof T,
  T extends { [key in K]: any[] },
>(aryKey: K): (node: T) => T[K] { ...
```

Note the `[key in K]` instead of `[key: K]`.